# Overlapping routes are not working in Koa.js

Tags: javascript, typescript, koa, koala, koa-router

When I call `/my/abc/create`, I always get status 400 because of the first entrypoint.
How can I call second endpoint? I prefer not to change the entrypoint order.

```js
var Router = require('koa-router');

var router = Router();


router.get('/my/:path/:id', (ctx) =>{
    if (isNaN(Number(cox.params.id))) { // if not numeric
        ctx.status = 400;
        return;
    }
    console.log('route id')
})
router.get('/my/:path/create', (ctx) =>{ 
    console.log('route create')
})
```

Comment: Register the create route first. `I prefer not to change the entrypoint order`. Why? That's the only solution.

Comment: oh is it an only solution? I thought there is a way...
I don't wanna change the order because I might have more entry points like create, so I don't want to care about order every time I make new one

Comment: My bad, definitely not the only solution, but the other solution requires checking in your first route if `ctx.params.id === 'create'` which is ugly.

Comment: yeah I thought about the solution too, but if I make many entry points like create, the code will be messy. I wanna avoid it

Comment: `so I don't want to care about order every time I make new one`. Well, if you don't want to care about the order, then you shouldn't make routes that can affect each other. For instance, the `create` route should probably be a POST and the `:id` route should probably be GET only. Typically, in RESTful design though, you don't have a verb like `create` in the URL, it's inferred by the fact that the request is a POST.

Comment: true, I think I should do that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RESTfully speaking, you wouldn't have a `create` route at all:

```
router.get('/my/:path/:id', (ctx) => /* get entity */)
router.post('/my/:path', (ctx) => /* create entity */)
router.patch('/my/:path/:id', (ctx) => /* update entity */)
router.delete('/my/:path/:id', (ctx) => /* delete entity */)
```